# Gradient Tracking Button with MUI

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

See the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/krakruhahah/pen/xxWrmYM) as example. I have a hover effect where the gradient follows the mouse cursor.

I have two CSS variables, `--x` and `--y` declated that are used to track the position of the mouse on the button.
The CSS variable `--size`, is used to modify the gradient's dimensions.

With `background: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, pink, transparent)` it creates the gradient at the correct position.

The `Document.querySelector()` and `EventTarget.addEventListener()` register a handler for the `'mousemove'` event.

And `Element.getBoundingClientRect()` and `CSSStyleDeclaration.setProperty()` updates the values of the `--x` and `--y` CSS variables.

Now I try to recreate it as styled component in React Typescript with MUI Button.
I declared the CSS styles in my styled Button but it is not applied.

`Button.tsx`

```
import React from 'react';
import { styled, Theme } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { Button, SxProps } from '@mui/material';

const HoverButton = styled(Button)(({ theme }) => ({
    borderRadius: 100,
    ".mouse-cursor-gradient-tracking": {
        position: "relative",
        background: "#7983ff",
        padding: "0.5rem 1rem",
        fontSize: "1.2rem",
        border: "none",
        color: theme.palette.secondary.contrastText,
        cursor: "pointer",
        outline: "none",
        overflow: "hidden",
      },
      
      ".mouse-cursor-gradient-tracking span": {
        position: "relative",
      },
      
      ".mouse-cursor-gradient-tracking:before": {
        --size: 0,
        content: '',
        position: "absolute",
        left: "var(--x)",
        top: "var(--y)",
        width: "var(--size)",
        height: "var(--size)",
        background: "radial-gradient(circle closest-side, pink, transparent)",
        transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
        transition: "width 0.2s ease, height 0.2s ease",
      },
      
      ".mouse-cursor-gradient-tracking:hover:before": {
        "--size": "200px"
      },
}));

export function SubmitButton(props: { children: React.ReactNode; sx?: SxProps<Theme> }) {
    let button:<Element | null> = document.querySelector('.mouse-cursor-gradient-tracking');
    button.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
        let rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
        let x = e.clientX - rect.left;
        let y = e.clientY - rect.top;
        button.style.setProperty('--x', x + 'px');
        button.style.setProperty('--y', y + 'px');
    });

    return (
        <HoverButton type="submit" variant="contained" sx={props.sx}>
            {props.children}<span>Hover me</span>
        </HoverButton>
    );
}
```

Comment: By 'not applied' do you mean that none of the styling shown here is applied, or only bits of it? Can you use your browser's dev tools inspect facility to see exactly what styling is being applied?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/zealous-danny-3g3fuh?file=/src/App.tsx).

And let me explain a few shortcomings of your approach.

1. Imperatively query selecting the button with a class and adding the event handler. Like below:

```
    let button:<Element | null> = document.querySelector('.mouse-cursor-gradient-tracking');
    button.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
        let rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
        let x = e.clientX - rect.left;
        let y = e.clientY - rect.top;
        button.style.setProperty('--x', x + 'px');
        button.style.setProperty('--y', y + 'px');
    });
```

You can instead add an event handler directly to a button component in React. So, React take care of how the event is added to the component.

```js
const Component = () => {

  const mouseDownHandler = (e) => {
    // logic here
  }
  
 return (<button onMouseDown={mouseDownHandler}>Click me</button>);
};
```

2. Using classes mixed with `styled` or `css-in-js`.

```js
const HoverButton = styled(Button)(({ theme }) => ({
    ".mouse-cursor-gradient-tracking": {
        position: "relative",
        background: "#7983ff",
      },
    ".mouse-cursor-gradient-tracking span": {
        position: "relative",
      },
      
      ".mouse-cursor-gradient-tracking:before": {
        --size: 0,
        content: '',
      },
      
      ".mouse-cursor-gradient-tracking:hover:before": {
        "--size": "200px"
      },
}));
```

Instead of this, you can simply do:

```js
const HoverButton = styled(Button)`  
  position: relative;
  background: #7983ff;

  & > span {
    ... your code here
  }

  &:before {
   ... your code here
  }
  
  &:hover:before {
   ... your code here
  } 
`;

const SubmitButton = () => {
 return <HoverButton>Text</HoverButton>
}
```

The style will be directly applied to the button with the pseudo-classes. Your separate custom class (css-in-js engine will create a class with a hash on its own) is not needed until and unless you are trying to override an existing class from another library.

3. Updating the styles dynamically.

```js
button.addEventListener('mousemove', e => {
  ...other codes
  button.style.setProperty('--x', x + 'px');
  button.style.setProperty('--y', y + 'px');
});
```

This won't update the styles of the buttons dynamically. We can use a state which can be updated with the handler mentioned in point no. 1 and pass them as a prop to the styled button and use it to change the css values.

Here is the full working code.

```js
import { useState } from "react";
import { styled, Theme } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { Button, SxProps } from "@mui/material";
import "./styles.css";

const StyledButton = styled(Button)<{ left: number; top: number }>`
  position: relative;
  background: #7983ff;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  overflow: hidden;

  &:before {
    content: "";
    left: ${({ left }) => left}px;
    top: ${({ top }) => top}px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    background: radial-gradient(circle closest-side, pink, transparent);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transition: width 0.2s ease, height 0.2s ease;
  }

  &:hover:before {
    color: red;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
  }
`;

const SubmitButton = (props: {
  children?: React.ReactNode;
  sx?: SxProps<Theme>;
}) => {
  const [hoverStyle, setHoverStyle] = useState({
    left: 0,
    top: 0
  });

  const handleMouseMove: React.MouseEventHandler<HTMLButtonElement> = (e) => {
    const rect = e.currentTarget.getBoundingClientRect();
    const left = e.clientX - rect.left;
    const top = e.clientY - rect.top;

    setHoverStyle({ left, top });
  };

  return (
    <StyledButton
      left={hoverStyle.left}
      top={hoverStyle.top}
      type="submit"
      variant="contained"
      sx={props.sx}
      onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
    >
      <span>Hover me</span>
    </StyledButton>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>
      <SubmitButton />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Links to the resources:
[MUI styled()](https://mui.com/system/styled/),
[Styled component props](https://mui.com/system/styled/)